# Flutter how to use popUntil without animation

Tags: flutter

You can remove animation on `.pop()` by using `PageRouteBuilder`. The `popUntil` method on the other hand only accepts a predicate as a parameter.

How can I use the `.popUntil` method without any animations?

I'm trying to achieve the following

```dart
// Pop the view to the root (multiple navigations)
Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);

// Navigate to the new route
Navigator.of(context)
    .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FooScreen()));
```

Comment: This may help https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pushAndRemoveUntil.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @user8773560 for pointing the `pushAndRemoveUntil` method.

This fixes the animation problem

```dart
Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FooScreen()),
  (route) => route.isFirst,
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me :)

```
int count = 0;
                       
 Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
 PageRouteBuilder(
           pageBuilder:
           (context, animation1, animation2) =>
            MembershipListScreen(),
        transitionDuration: Duration(seconds: 0),
                              ),
  (_) => count++ >= 3, //3 is count of your pages you want to pop
                );
```